# Copy the start of an InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream, reset

I want to copy the "start" (i.e., first N characters) of an InputStream and then reset the stream to its start, so that it can be reused.

Using mark() and reset() does not work for all types of input streams, so I was wondering if there is a "generic" open source Java class (i.e., a stream wrapper) that can do this for any type of input stream.

Also, what would be the safest way of making the copy to avoid conversion errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a bit of experimentation, it seems that the best (although imperfect) approach is to use the **mark()** and **reset()** methods of the InputStream.

If the original stream does not support marking/resetting, an easy workaround is to wrap it inside a **BufferedInputStream**.*

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you could wrap your InputStream in a [`PushbackInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html) so you could read the first N bytes then [`unread()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html#unread%28byte%5b%5d%29) them for reuse of the stream.

Comment: This is only useful if one wants to deal with the PushbackInputStream only, which works by just pre-buffering.

Comment: +1 Didn't know about PushbackInputStream - it's cool! And I think the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at how apache commons IOUtils copies stream [IOUtils#copyLarge()](http://www.google.com/codesearch#SS2by_AKaLs/src/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.java&type=cs&l=1020).

You can use populate ab `ByteArrayInputStream` such a way.

- `byte[] buffer = new byte[n];` // n is the size from start
- pupulate the buffer using technique from `IOUtils#copyLarge()`
- create your ByteArrayInputStream using the `buffer` you created earlier

Here is the code snippet to `IOUtils#copyLarge()`

```
public static long copyLarge(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
        throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    long count = 0;
    int n = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
        count += n;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have looked at that and much more source code from the Commons IO, but what I want is to leave the original stream reset to its start.

Comment: @PNS: Sorry for being late to response. How about calling reset method end of reading n byte data, though not all subclass of InputStream does not override default implementation. And default implementation throw an exception.

Comment: Yes, I think mark() and reset() are the closest to what I want, and if the stream does not offer that, i.e. markSupported() returns false, one can always wrap it inside a BufferedInputStream and use that, instead.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to reusing a stream and size doesn't matter (e.g. a few mega bytes), getting the `byte[]` of the stream once, and then recreating `ByteArrayInputStream` objects with the stored `byte[]` when necessary has always worked for me. No more trouble with `mark()` and `reset()`.

Comment: You mean, reading all the stream into a byte array and then reusing it? Can't do that, because the input size in my application can be very large.